# Spring LDAP vs Apache LDAP api vs ?, which could be the best LDAP api?

Tags: java, node.js, groovy, ldap

I am about to start a new project around MS AD and Apache LDAP servers. So far now I have java in my mind to implement it but I am open to other open source options too like node, python etc. Some of questions in mind are

- Which API is most versatile/flexible to connect any LDAP?
- Which one is most actively developed and supported?
- Which have the most active and biggest community?

Comment: not clear what do you need. to connect ldap to get users, groups, validate password - you don't need any library... and to compare between java, python, node - to choose a programming language the "ldap" is the only criteria ???

Comment: To connect, query and do operations in LDAP, I am aware about two library/framework in Java i.e Apache LDAP API, Spring LDAP but I am not sure/aware about their shortcomings. So my question is to identify best API created and maintained for LDAP ops, by best I mean to have superset of functions available for Apache LDAP and MS LDAP.

Comment: @daggett I don't understand why I won't need a library, let me give you a concrete example: a web app to handle self password reset, this does not come out of the box so has to be implemented

Comment: to verify password, read attributes, read groups - no libraries required... btw what about servers like [keycloak.org](https://www.keycloak.org/index.html) or [wso2is](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS541/WSO2+Identity+Server+Documentation)

Comment: We are using apache LDAP and Microsoft Active Directory. Well I am still not convinced about 'no libraries required', you might be on linux and using 'ldapsearch' from command line but it is a client, you may call it application or api or library to communicate with LDAP server. When I will making up a web application for the same reason, I will need some kind of API/library to converts user entered inputs and make server calls in LDAP protocol and get response in LDAP format and convert and show it user in a friendly format

Comment: search for `javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext` ldap examples. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/src/Simple.java